# How do I find the value of the key that I set with argument in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am currently working on a project with Ruby.
I don't know how to find the set of the value and key that has the same key as I gave with argument.

what I have tried is something like this below.
but it doesn't work.

```
def find_target(type)
    target = type_list.find{|k,v| k == type}
    target
end


def type_list 
  type = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4
   }
  type
end
```

but instead of giving an argument of variable, I gave a string as an argument, and it worked.

```
def find_target(a)
    target = type_list.find{|k,v| k == a}
    target
end
```

- Edited
  What I really want find_target to do is returning a matched value.
  For example, when an argument is a, then it returns 1.

How can I solve this?

I would love you if you could help me.
Thank you .

Comment: Your object `{a: 1, b: 2, ...}` shouldn't really be thought of as a "list". This is a **`Hash`**. Take a look at [the ruby documentation for `Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D), and you'll see the standard approach for retrieving values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one thing tripping you up is that your `type_list` hash is keyed with symbols (rather than strings or the value of a variable). The syntax you're using:

```
{a: 1}
```

is just shorthand for this:

```
{:a => 1}
```

Which means "A Hash with one key: the symbol `:a` with the value `1`". That's distinct from:

```
{'a' => 1} # Keyed with the string 'a'
```

and this:

```
a = 'something'
b = {a => 1} # Keyed with value of 'a' at the time of creating, ie: {'something' => 1}. Note that if you change the value of a, the hash key won't change.
```

What do you expect as your return value from `find_target(:a)`? The `find` method on a Hash will return an [Enumerator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) - mostly equivalent to a two-element Array, with the key and the value: `{a: 1}.find{|k,v|k == :a}` will return `[:a, 1]`. Is that what you want?

If you just want to have the value `1` returned, then you're really doing a hash lookup, and you don't need any extra methods at all. A common way to do this would be to define `type_list` as a constant, and then just refer to it by key:

```
TYPE_LIST = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
}

#Then to find the type:
TYPE_LIST[:a] # Returns '1'
```

You might want to use a `find_type` method to handle the case where the key doesn't match a type: a plain Hash lookup will return `nil`, which you might not want.

Hope this helps put you on the right path, but I'm happy to expand this answer if needed!

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. What I really want is that I want to create a method that returns value depends on the argument given. So if `a` is given as an argument, I want it to return `1`. I am going to use `find_target` in a crawler that gives `find_target` different argument each time. So I thought, I need to create a method to find a matched value.

Comment: @Abel Does `def find_target(type); type_list[type.to_sym] end` do the job? I think that's what @BenHull's answer indicates.

Comment: Whether you use a method, or just lookup on a Hash (or some other way) really depends on what you want to happen if the key is not found. If you want it to just return `nil`, then @BenStephens snippet will do the trick. If you want to raise an error or provide a default value, then you'll need a bit more logic in the method. Happy to add more to the answer if you can provide a bit more info.

Comment: I am sorry for not understanding your comment completely, and thank you so much for kind advices. I could get the result I wanted with `type.to_sym`. I put the array result into the variable list, and I could get the value with list[1].
Thank you both so much.